# C, How is getopt() updating

Tags: c, getopt

I'm trying to make sense of a section of skeleton code for a class. The intended usage would be:

```
./a.out -d -n Foo -i Bar
```

The skeleton code works fine, but I have never used `getopt()` and can't understand why it works correctly (understanding it has nothing to do with the assignment, I just want to make sense of it). How is it that it updates / exits the while loop? I don't see a pointer increment or the arguments passed to it in the loop change at all.

```
char *optString = "-d-n:-i:";
int opt = getopt(argc, argv, optString);

while (opt != -1) {
    switch(opt) {
    case 'd':
        debug = 1;
        break;
    case 'n':
        nameserver_flag = 1;
        nameserver = optarg;
        break;
    case 'i':
        hostname = optarg;
        break;
    case '?':
        usage();
        exit(1);
    default:
        usage();
        exit(1);
    }
    opt = getopt(argc, argv, optString);
}
```

Comment: The libc providing `getopt` is free software. Just study the source code if you want to understand in details how it works. And you might also use `argp` functions.

Comment: See [getopt.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=posix/getopt.c;hb=HEAD) from GNU libc.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, thank you, that helps a lot more than the man pages for making sense of why it works. It looks like `optarg` is the hidden index

Comment: As Alex Brault pointed out in my answer (that I deleted) `optarg` is not the hidden index. I'll read it more thoroughly

Comment: @asimes: The most important point is that `getopt` defines global variables that it later uses to resume its execution. Exactly how they work (with the exception of the 4 public ones) is an implementation detail and really isn't important beyond knowing that it saves state in memory and reads it back.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to have some idea of what it was doing to achieve its service. At first it just didn't make sense how it was possible until I realized there were hidden variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getopt` uses global variables to store the argument index, the next character to parse and some other information. Each time you call `getopt`, the function checks these variables to know where it last was (or where you told it it was) and updates the variables for the next call.

Most importantly, `optind` stores the index in `argv` of the next element to be scanned.

Answer (score 2):

Each call to getopt processes one more of the arguments in argv, returning the result in opt, etc. etc. What else is there to understand?

Comment: The argument it takes in the while loop doesn't update in any visible way

Comment: Yes, argv doesn't change. getopt maintains state with a variable you don't see, included in the header file. opt does change however, that's how your switch statement works. See 'man getopt' for details.